# Socket Descriptor Changed After Call to recvfrom

Tags: c, network-programming, udp, recv

EDIT: Removed code/explanation because this project has been given again and students can easily find the solution via this post.

To clarify what happened, I simply passed the wrong length/size in my recvfrom() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
if(recvfrom( temp->sockfd, sendHostIP, BUFFER_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recvAddr, &recvLen) < 0)
    errorMsg("recvfrom");
```

You pass `BUFFER_LEN` as the length (256), but `sendHostIP` is only of length `MAXHOSTNAMELEN` (64).

This causes `recvfrom()` to overflow that buffer.  The same problem occurs when you read in to `localHostIP`.

Comment: Oh man, that's right.  I must have copy/pasted the array size incorrectly.  Thanks!